# How to group only sequences of the same value

Tags: r, dplyr

I've got a column in a `data.frame` that consists sequences of the same value. I would like to group a `data.frame` by this column, but for me if the same value is not in subsequent rows - it doesn't form a group. So with a data like below:

```
structure(list(var = c(0.753821034682915, 0.753821034682915, 
0.846493156161159, 0.140008716611192, 0.140008716611192, 0.140008716611192, 
0.140008716611192, 0.753821034682915, 0.846493156161159, 0.770532198715955, 
0.846493156161159, 0.140008716611192, 0.770532198715955, 0.770532198715955, 
0.770532198715955, 0.846493156161159, 0.770532198715955, 0.846493156161159, 
0.770532198715955, 0.846493156161159)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
```

I would expect the groups are:

```
structure(list(var = c(0.753821034682915, 0.753821034682915, 
0.846493156161159, 0.140008716611192, 0.140008716611192, 0.140008716611192, 
0.140008716611192, 0.753821034682915, 0.846493156161159, 0.770532198715955, 
0.846493156161159, 0.140008716611192, 0.770532198715955, 0.770532198715955, 
0.770532198715955, 0.846493156161159, 0.770532198715955, 0.846493156161159, 
0.770532198715955, 0.846493156161159), group = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
```

Then I could use just `group_by(group)`. How can I achieve that?

Comment: `library(data.table);

rleid(df$var)` will create a series of ids that change when the `var` value changes. More info here: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.11.4/topics/rleid

Answer (score 3):

A `dplyr` option

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(group = c(0, cumsum(diff(var) != 0)) + 1)
#         var group
#1  0.7538210     1
#2  0.7538210     1
#3  0.8464932     2
#4  0.1400087     3
#5  0.1400087     3
#6  0.1400087     3
#7  0.1400087     3
#8  0.7538210     4
#9  0.8464932     5
#10 0.7705322     6
#11 0.8464932     7
#12 0.1400087     8
#13 0.7705322     9
#14 0.7705322     9
#15 0.7705322     9
#16 0.8464932    10
#17 0.7705322    11
#18 0.8464932    12
#19 0.7705322    13
#20 0.8464932    14
```

---

### Sample data

```
df <- structure(list(var = c(0.753821034682915, 0.753821034682915,
0.846493156161159, 0.140008716611192, 0.140008716611192, 0.140008716611192,
0.140008716611192, 0.753821034682915, 0.846493156161159, 0.770532198715955,
0.846493156161159, 0.140008716611192, 0.770532198715955, 0.770532198715955,
0.770532198715955, 0.846493156161159, 0.770532198715955, 0.846493156161159,
0.770532198715955, 0.846493156161159)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-20L))
```

Comment: The `dplyr` is not at all essential since cumsum() is base R:  `df[["group"]] <- c(0, cumsum(diff(df[["var"]]) != 0)) + 1`

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to use base R you could do this:

```
rep(seq_along(rle(df$var)$lengths), rle(df$var)$lengths)
[1]  1  1  2  3  3  3  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  9  9 10 11 12 13 14
```

but I prefer the `data.table` solution as well. :)